# MVC 5 Routing with parameter using @Url.RouteUrl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ActionResult that I have applied a routing attribute to:

```
[Route("myproduct/{productID}", Name = "myproduct")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Products", ParentKey = "products", Key = "myproducts")]
public ActionResult myproducts(int productID) ...
```

I am trying to link to the view via a RouteUrl:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("myproducts", @Model.myproducts[i].productID)">Buy</a>
```

The resulting html does not even include a href:

```
<a>Buy</a>
```

If I remove the parameter it works:

```
[Route("myproducts", Name = "myproducts")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Products", ParentKey = "home", Key = "myproducts")]
public ActionResult myproducts(int productID) ...


<a href="/products/myproducts">Book</a>
```

Am I trying to add the parameter incorrectly? The documentation suggests what I am attempting.

Route Config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );            
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your route configuration? I suspect it's a positional problem with how your routes are defined. i.e. default route would be {controller}/{action}/{id} (optional) These placeholder names are not abitrary. But you have {productId} which maybe messing up your routing which is why you are not getting anything. What happens when you nav to /products/myproducts/45 in your browser? I suspect a 404.

Comment: I have added the route config. I am getting 404 on every derivative of the url. I have also tried just hard coding the url instead of using the @Url tag and 404 every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("myproducts", new { productID = Model.myproducts[i].productID })
```

And change your action route like:

```
[Route("myproducts/{productID}", Name = "myproducts")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Products", ParentKey = "home", Key = "myproducts")]
public ActionResult myproducts(int productID) {

}
```

Comment: thank you - changed how I was passing the parameter 'new { productID = Model.myproducts[i].productID }'.

Answer (score 3):

I can see a couple of issues:

- The parameter is not being passed correctly, as you are passing the productId directly as the second parameter of the [`Url.RouteUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl(v=vs.118).aspx) method. You should pass it correctly (and be careful so it matches the name of the parameter in the route), for example using an anonymous object:

  ```
  @Url.RouteUrl("myproduct", new { productID = Model.myproducts[i].productID })
  ```
- The name of the route in the attribute and the name in the @Url helper are different (See **myproduct** Vs **myproducts**):

  ```
  [Route("myproduct/{productID}", Name = "myproduct")]
  @Url.RouteUrl("myproducts", @Model.myproducts[i].productID)
  ```